# Can't get data in Firefox and IE9 but it works fine in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have this method

```
 function callCommentservice() {
        try {

            // Comment Service Url
         var getCommentServiceUrl = self.commentsServiceUrl + self.getRating + "tenantId=" + self.tenantId + "&ratedObjectTypeId=" + self.ratedObjectTypeId + "&ratedObjectId=" + self.ratedObjectId + "&ratingType=" + self.ratingType + "&start=" + self.start + "&totalRecordsNeeded=" + self.totalRecordsNeeded;


         $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
             url: getCommentServiceUrl,
             contentType: "application/json",
             timeout: 5000,
             beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                 xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
             },
         dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 alert("I m in here.............!!!!");

                 //                    if (success == data) {

                 // Assigning totalRecordsNeeded value to global variable pagination_parameters.pageSize
                 pagination_parameters.pageSize = self.totalRecordsNeeded;

                 //Printing on a console.
                 debug("get comments url: " + getCommentServiceUrl);

                 // Calling Service in order to get data.
                 //                        $.getJSON(getCommentServiceUrl + "&callback=?", function (data) {
                 var emptyCommentHyperlink = document.getElementById('emptyCommentHyperlink');
                 // when there is no comment available in a service than this block will work.
                 if (data.length == 0) {

                     emptyCommentHyperlink.style.display = 'block';
                     //emptyCommentHyperlink.onclick = addCommentsBox;
                     $("#emptyCommentHyperlink").click(addCommentsBox);
                 }
                 else {

                     emptyCommentHyperlink.style.display = 'none';
                 }

                 //printing on a console.
                 debug("Date from the get service:" + data);
                 //alert(data);

                 // Changing date format of a service element AddedDateTime.
                 for (var key = 0; key < data.length; key++) {


                     var dataArray = data[key];

                     // Printing on console.
                     debug("data Array after the data object:" + dataArray);
                     var jsonDate = dataArray.AddedDateTime; //AddedDateTime is the service element.'

                     // Printing on a console.
                     debug("converted Time" + jsonDate);

                     var oneSecond = 1000;       // milliseconds in one seconds
                     // changing format of the AddedDateTime
                     var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substring(6)));

                     var year = date.getFullYear(); // 2011
                     var day = date.getDay();
                     var exactdate = date.getDate();
                     var month = date.getMonth();
                     var hours = date.getHours();
                     var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                     var month_names_short = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

                     // Fromating Absolute time over tooltip.
                     if (hours > 12) {
                         hours = hours - 12;
                         var exact = zeroPad(hours) + ":" + zeroPad(minutes) + " PM" + ", " + exactdate + " " + month_names_short[month] + " " + year;
                     }
                     else {

                         var exact = zeroPad(hours) + ":" + zeroPad(minutes) + " AM" + ", " + exactdate + " " + month_names_short[month] + " " + year;
                     }

                     // subtracting current date with the comment date.
                     var finalDate = Math.abs(new Date() - date) / oneSecond;

                     dataArray.time_duration = new TimeSpan(finalDate).toString();

                     // Printing on a console.
                     debug("finalDate: " + dataArray.time_duration);

                     //alert(dataArray.time_duration);
                     dataArray.Absolute_Date = exact;

                 }


                 // Extracting TotalCount from service.
                 var totalComments = data[0].TotalCount;
                 // alert(totalComments);


                 //Calling paging Function
                 pages(totalComments);

                 //Making the commenttable empty.
                 $('#commentDiv').empty();

                 // Printing on a console.
                 debug("data before mactache" + data);

                 var comments = { "Comments": data };
                 var html = Mustache.to_html(self.template_html, comments);
                 var target_div = document.getElementById("commentDiv");
                 target_div.innerHTML = html;
                 //alert("target_div");


                 //                        });

             },

             //                },
             error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                 debug(xhr);

                 var errorMsg = document.getElementById('ErrorLable');
                 errorMsg.style.display = "block";
             }
         });
        }

        catch (err) {
            //Printing on a console.
            debug("callCommentservice");
            debug(err);

        }
    }
```

this method working fine in Chrome and Safari but not working in in I.E 9 and firefox , I receive an error 405 in firefox request header is as follows :-

> Response Headers Allow
>   GET Content-Length  1565
>   Content-Type    text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8 Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-Powered-By  ASP.NET
>   Access-Control-Allow-Orig...  * 
>   Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    POST, GET,
>   OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Head...  CONTENT-TYPE, 
>   Accept Access-Control-Max-Age   1728000
>    Date   Wed, 14 Dec 2011 10:30:43 GMT
>
> Request Headers Host  services.farooq.tv 
>   User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
>   Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language   en-us,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding  gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 
>   Connection  keep-alive
>   Origin    http://marketplace.softech-lp35.softech.us
>   Access-Control-Request-Me...  GET
>   Access-Control-Request-He...  content-type

Comment: "Cant get data in firefox .. but working fine in .. fire fox"?

Comment: The headers are badly formatted and truncated. Can you post them more readable. In any case: HTTP error 405 sounds like the server is unhappy with the request, so you may need to ask its operator.

Comment: but why operator is only unhappy in case of firefox and I.E why not in case of chrome and safari?????

Comment: @BASEER HAIDER: Its most likely impossible to say for us. This is a server application specific problem, and it's not our server. Can you post the (complete and readable) request and response headers **and** contents from both Firefox and a browser in works it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue in contentType: "application/json", I have removed it from $.ajax function now its working fine.